# Is is possible to cast a simple block of code to a struct?

Tags: c

Consider this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  struct test {
    int i;
    int t;
  };

  struct test hello = (struct test) {
    .i = 0, 
    .t = 1
  };

  printf("%d, %d\n", hello.i, hello.t);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0, 1
```

my question is what is this line `(struct test) {.i = 0, .t = 1 }` doing?

is it casting a block of code to type struct test? is that even possible?

if not please tell me what is it doing, and thanks.

Comment: It's called [compound literal](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.2/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).

Comment: So it's a cast ?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca oh ok, got it :))

Comment: @Jabberwocky, Gotcha

Comment: @Hádēs see also [this](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`struct test hello = (struct test) { .i = 0, .t = 1 };` uses two features of C called *compound literals* and *designated initializers*.

The general form of a compound literal is: `(` *type-name* `)` `{` *initializer-list* `}`. (There may also be a comma after the list.) For example, these are compound literals:

```
(int) { 3 }
(int []) { 0, 1, 2 }
(union { float f; unsigned int u; }) = { 3.4 }
```

A compound literal is an object with no name.

In a plain initializer list, you simply list values for the items in the object being initialized. However, you can also use designated initializers. A designated initializer uses either the name of a structure member or the index of an array element to specify which part of the object is to be given the indicated value:

```
{ struct { int a, b, c; }) = { .b = 4, .c = 1, .a = 9 }
(int a[1024]) = { [473] = 1, [978] = -1 }
```

So, in `struct test hello = (struct test) { .i = 0,  .t = 1 };`, we are creating `struct test` with `i` initialized to 0, and `t` initialized to 1. Then this `struct test` is used to initialize another struct test named `hello`.

That particular use is pointless, since it creates a temporary object for the purpose of something that could have been done directly. Nominally, it creates a temporary `struct test` which is initialized and then copied into the `struct test hello`. Then the temporary `struct test` has no further use. The effect is the same as simply writing `struct test hello = { .i = 0, .t = 1};`. That initializes `hello` without using a temporary object. However, a good compiler will optimize them to the same code.

Comment: not only is it pointless, but it doesn't work in file scope... and it is a sign of cargo culting...

Comment: its pointless in the code I've provided, but if I want to return a struct from a function and initialize it with the function's parameter it's not useless right?

Comment: `struct test new(int i, int t) {`
  `return (struct test) { .i = i, .t = t };`
`}`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It does work at file scope. I just tested that in Apple Clang 1000.11.45.5 with `-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil strange indeed, it shouldn't. GCC doesn't allow. "error: initializer element is not constant [-Wpedantic]"

Comment: @Hádēs: My statement is not that compound literals are useless, my statement is that using a compound literal **only** to initialize an identical structure is useless. It is like writing `int temporary = 3; int x = temporary;`, where `temporary` is never used again, instead of writing `int x = 3;`. Nominally, it creates an object that was not needed at all.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Got it, :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil confirmed, that's definitely a bug in clang. Doesn't compile [in MSVC at all](https://godbolt.org/z/dE8U7R).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: The fact that compilers differ does not mean there is a bug.

Comment: @EricPostpischil non-standards conforming if there is a constraint violation

Comment: And the said constraint is [C11 6.7.9p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p4)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: It seems Clang regards it as a constant expression, and GCC does not.

Answer (score 3):

In C (and many related programming languages), the curly braces often mean:

`{` this is where the code starts
`}` this is where the code ends

They can also have several different meanings though. They don't only refer to code, but also to data structures:

```
struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

In this case they define where the data structure begins and ends.

```
struct point pythagoras = {
    .x = 3,
    .y = 4
};
```

And in this case they define where the initial contents of the variable begins and ends.

In conclusion, the `{` means begin, and the `}` means end. Nothing more.

The "code" that initializes your `struct test` is not really code, although it really looks like it. Here it is again:

```
struct test hello = (struct test) {
    .i = 0, 
    .t = 1
};
```

Usually, the `(type)` means a type cast. But, in this case the `(struct test)` is followed by an opening brace `{`, and this combination is called a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal). It's a literal for a variable of a compound data type.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks, I added some more explanation.